# Socket server on multiple ports performance

Tags: php

I want to build a game in AS3 and do most of the logic in PHP/MySQL since I'm more experienced in PHP than in any other language that was recommended for it like JAVA.

I've read a lot about that PHP is not a good option for a PHP socket server. The main reason was that it will not manage to handle more than about 1000 clients.

But I never found a good reply why actually it is like that? Is the PHP process crashing after it? Is it an option to set up for example 2 socket servers on different ports? Will it handle about 2000 clients then? Or still not?

Comment: Perhaps a better question is: why should it perform better? PHP is a web programming language designed to generate HTML. It is not designed to act as a server.

Comment: Question was not "what PHP was built for?" but about the performance of using it as a socket server. We all know PHP evolved a lot since the beginning and can be succesfuly used for varaiety of purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know AS, I would actually recommend either Java or Node, actually. AS3 is very similar to both Java and JavaScript (some differences), which would make the conversion pretty painless. The magic you have to decide on is how many messages go through each of your clients per second.
If the load is light, prefer Node. If the load is heavy, prefer Java.

If, however, you want to stick to PHP, you will need multiple game instances running from CLI (**NOT** from Apache). You can then connect to them through standard sockets in any way you like. This is easy to do.

The hard bit is to synchronize all the instances. You can do so by having them all connect to an instance that is solely dedicated to relaying messages to the servers, or have them connect between each other. Game comms theory books and tutorials will come in handy on how to do this.

Your other issues will be, if using PHP, amongst others:

- The socket connection limit per daemon
- Single-threaded nature of PHP
- Caching
- Building an evented multi-client socket interface from something that, inherently, does not have this

PHP is at a severe disadvantage compared to Java on this. It is, however, possible.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. I'm aware of most of those disadvantages, however I don't need super fast performance that's why I wanted to try it with the language I know. I think I will do some tests and if it won't be good enought I'll try Java as you suggested.

Comment: @YiiSlave: Java might be too overkill. If you can, and your game is not very bandwidth-hungry, you may want to try Node still.